Azure AI Search Error: Parameter name: $skip Exception Details: ParameterValueOutOfRange Value must be between 0 and 100000
When I executed the below code, it is resulting in
raise HttpResponseError(response=response, model=error)
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (InvalidRequestParameter) Value must be between 0 and 100000.  
Code: InvalidRequestParameter
Message: Value must be between 0 and 100000.
Parameter name: $skip
Exception Details:      (ParameterValueOutOfRange) Value must be between 0 and 100000.
        Code: ParameterValueOutOfRange
        Message: Value must be between 0 and 100000.

Number of documents in my knowledge base is just 14000 but I don't understand why it is exceeding 100,000.
Code snippet is shown below:
import asyncio
import os
import semantic_kernel as sk
from semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai import AzureTextCompletion,AzureChatCompletion
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.search.documents.models import QueryType
from services import Service

# Initialize the Semantic Kernel
kernel = sk.Kernel()

# Initialize Azure Cognitive Search client
search_client = SearchClient(
    endpoint=AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT,
    index_name=AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
    credential=AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY)
)

class SearchPlugin:
    def search_documents(self, query: str) -> str:
        search_parameters = {
            "top": 50,  # Number of results to return
            "skip": 0   # Number of results to skip
        }
        results = search_client.search(search_text=query, query_type=QueryType.SIMPLE)
        #, **search_parameters)
        print("Number of documents = ", len(list(results)))
        response = [doc['content'] for doc in results]
        return '\n'.join(response)


# Manually register the plugins with the kernel
plugins = {"SearchPlugin": SearchPlugin()}

# Define a function to interact with the AI agent
def interact_with_agent(plugins, plugin_name, function_name, **kwargs):
    plugin = plugins.get(plugin_name)
    if not plugin:
        raise ValueError(f"Plugin {plugin_name} not found.")
    func = getattr(plugin, function_name, None)
    if not func:
        raise ValueError(f"Function {function_name} not found in plugin {plugin_name}.")
    return func(**kwargs)

# System prompt for the chat completion
prompt = "You are an AI language model assistant."
from semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai import OpenAIChatPromptExecutionSettings
from semantic_kernel.prompt_template import InputVariable, PromptTemplateConfig

selectedService = Service.AzureOpenAI
service_id="gpt-4o"
chat_completion = AzureChatCompletion(service_id=service_id,
    endpoint=AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT,
    api_key=AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY,
    deployment_name=AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME
)

kernel.add_service(chat_completion)

execution_settings = kernel.get_prompt_execution_settings_from_service_id(
    service_id=service_id
)

execution_settings.max_tokens = 2000
execution_settings.temperature = 0.7
execution_settings.top_p = 0.8

prompt_template_config = PromptTemplateConfig(
    template=prompt,
    name="PMI Chatbot",
    template_format="semantic-kernel",
    input_variables=[
        InputVariable(name="input", description="The user input", is_required=True),
    ],
    execution_settings=execution_settings,
)

Respnose_Func = kernel.add_function(
    function_name=interact_with_agent(plugins, "SearchPlugin", "search_documents", query=service_query), 
    plugin_name="SearchPlugin",
    prompt_template_config=prompt_template_config,
)
   
# Run your prompt
# Note: functions are run asynchronously
async def main():
    input_text = "What is Project Management"
    result = await kernel.invoke(Respnose_Func, input=input_text)
    print(result) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Can someone please help me to make the above code executable? TIA
I tried surfing internet but I didn't get the solution. I am expecting this code to run without error.

To address the issue with the Azure AI Search error regarding the $skip parameter value being out of range, we need to ensure that the value for $skip is within the valid range of 0 to 100,000. The error message  indicates that the value of $skipis exceeding this limit.

Add the search_client.search method should correctly use the skip and top parameters to iterate over the results without exceeding the Azure AI Search limits.

The code below integrates Azure Cognitive Search with Azure OpenAI services using Semantic Kernel in Python
I referred to this link for using Azure OpenAI on your data with Semantic Kernel.
I referred to this for Azure Search using Python.
import asyncio
import os
import semantic_kernel as sk
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient
from azure.search.documents.models import QueryType
from semantic_kernel.connectors.ai.open_ai import AzureChatCompletion
from semantic_kernel.prompt_template import InputVariable, PromptTemplateConfig
from azure.core.exceptions import HttpResponseError, ClientAuthenticationError

AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT = "PUT-YOUR-SEARCH-ENDPOINT-HERE"
AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME = "indexnmae"
AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY =  "PUT-YOUR-SEARCH-API-KEY-HERE"


kernel = sk.Kernel()


search_client = SearchClient(
    endpoint=AZURE_SEARCH_ENDPOINT,
    index_name=AZURE_SEARCH_INDEX_NAME,
    credential=AzureKeyCredential(AZURE_SEARCH_API_KEY)
)


class SearchPlugin:
    def search_documents(self, query: str, skip: int, top: int) -> str:
        search_parameters = {
            "skip": skip,
            "top": top,
        }
        try:
            results = search_client.search(search_text=query, query_type=QueryType.SIMPLE, **search_parameters)
            
          
            for doc in results:
                print("Document:", doc)
            
        
            response = [doc.get('description', 'No description available') for doc in results]
            return '\n'.join(response)
        except ClientAuthenticationError as auth_err:
            print(f"Authentication error: {auth_err}")
            return "Authentication error: Unable to authenticate with Azure Cognitive Search."
        except HttpResponseError as http_err:
            print(f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err}")
            return f"HTTP error occurred: {http_err.response.status_code} - {http_err.message}"


plugins = {"SearchPlugin": SearchPlugin()}


service_id = "gpt-4o"
chat_completion = AzureChatCompletion(
    service_id=service_id,
    endpoint="AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT",
    api_key="AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY",
    deployment_name="AZURE_OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME"
)


kernel.add_service(chat_completion)


prompt_template_config = PromptTemplateConfig(
    template="You are an AI language model assistant.",
    name="PMI Chatbot",
    template_format="semantic-kernel",
    input_variables=[
        InputVariable(name="input", description="The user input", is_required=True),
    ],
)

s
async def main():
   
    service_query = "What is Project Management"
    
   
    skip = 0
    top = 50
    
    
    search_function = plugins["SearchPlugin"].search_documents
    
    
    result = search_function(query=service_query, skip=skip, top=top)
    
    print(result) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())



Output:

